# Do we need a mutex to store a semaphore in c++?

Tags: c++, mutex, semaphore

For example if i have to store the available number of printer slots that are free as a semaphore. Since any two threads/users can access(update) that semaphore at the same time. So do i need to use mutex to apply locking concept on it?

Comment: Semaphores are already thread safe (their primary purpose is, after all, to be used by multiple threads). Although I might prefer an [atomic variable counter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), which seems a bit more intuitive for this sort of thing.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a semaphore or how to use one?

Comment: Calling `wait` on the semaphore takes care of the decrement and blocks if necessary. Calling `signal` on the semaphore does the increment and `wakens` if necessary.

Comment: What implementation of semaphores do you use? Have you read the documentation? It doesn't look like that from your question. Or are you trying to implement one yourself?